# ${\rm{E}}\left[ {{\rm{X - Y|2X + Y}}} \right]$ given that X and Y are correlated Gaussian r.v.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Assuming that $X \sim N\left( {0,a} \right)$, $Y \sim N\left( {0,b} \right)$ and that they have a correlation of $\rho $, can we compute ${\rm{E}}\left[ {{\rm{X - Y|2X + Y}}} \right]$

Comment: We can if $(X,Y)$ is assumed to be bivariate normal.

Comment: So, nothing insightful we can say in this set up?

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer unless the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is explicitly mentioned.